# null value added when using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to put all the data in a text file into a single String variable with the knowledge that I have and it runs fine but the output shows the following:

```
nullRead File Test
```

I used to replaceAll methods to try and remove the null but it doesn't work. Why is this null showing and how can I get rid of it?

Relevant Source Code:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Scanner readWatched;
    String fileData;

    public void handleFile() {
        try {
            readWatched = new Scanner(new File("E:\\Watched.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void readFile() {
        try {
            while (readWatched.hasNext()) {
                fileData += readWatched.next() + " ";
            }
            fileData.replaceAll("null", " ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(fileData);
    }

    public void closeFile() {
        readWatched.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an `Object` `fileData` defaults to `null` so its initial `String` value is translated to the String literal `"null"` as per [JLS 15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1.1) when appended to another String. Therefore it needs to be initialized:

```
private String fileData = "";
```

Consider using a `StringBuilder` here

Comment: Thank you but why doesn't the replaceAll method replace it with a space?

Comment: Youre attempting to replace a `String` literal "null" in `fileData` which is not the same as `null` - the lack of an assigned value. Even if `null` was used it would not work as an `NPE` would result...